# How to save long string as image to SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a long string which contain an image. I need to save it as an image to sql server using c# asp.net Following is the string. Please anyone share sample code to achieve the same. Thanks in advance.

```
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
```

Comment: In what kind of encoding does it strore an image?

Comment: This is base 64 string. I need to store this string in sql server and want to get back the same string. Kindly help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your string is in base64 format:

```
byte[] image=Convert.FromBase64String('your string');
```

Comment: Thanks, it is successfully save to database as byte not image. Here i have a question that will it save my all above photograph string because i delete half of the photograph string?

Comment: you should convert entire string

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I have tested it. First i have inserted this byte[] into database then get it back and try to convert back to its orignal string like you can see string in my first/orignal thread it gives me this error: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters. Please help, thanks.

Comment: what is your data type in database?edit your question and write entire code